# Emails send from Rails using SendGrid are going to spam folder in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I am using `SendGrid` with Rails to send emails. But when I am sending email from production then all emails are going to spam folder. `default from` address is set fine.

what are the things that I shall check to make sure that emails are not going into spam folder.

Any hints on where to start debugging will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my main problem was that my domain name was not Authenticated with SendGrid. Once I Authenticated my domain then all emails start showing up in inbox. Here is documentation on how to Authenticate your domain in SendGrid. [link](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

Staying out of spam inboxes is not an exact science, I'm afraid. But there are some things you can do to give your emails the best chance.

Here's an article with [10 tips for stopping your email going to spam](https://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/). I think the most important technical suggestion is to [authenticate your email using SPF, DKIM, DMARC and BIMI](https://sendgrid.com/blog/10-tips-to-keep-email-out-of-the-spam-folder/#authenticate). [The documentation for setting up domain authentication on SendGrid is here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/how-to-set-up-domain-authentication).